# Where in the standard is the grammar for the template argument in, e.g., `std::function<int(char)>` defined?

Tags: c++

Just for curiosity and educational reasons, I'm trying to find where in the C++ standard it defines the `int(char)` in `std::function<int(char)>` to be valid. It's not particularly easy to search for any permutation of the words template, argument, function, function type, etc. The best definition I can put together would be `template instantiation template argument function type specifier`...

Comment: `int(char)` isn't related to templates, it's a plain function type.

Comment: I cannot point you to the standard (hence i dont write an answer), but this might help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: Note that you have the same _type name_ when you write `using foo = int(char); std::function<foo>`. This shows what Mat explained.

Answer (score 1):

A type name is a [declaration without the name of the notional thing declared](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#1), much as can appear as a parameter in a function declaration.  A [*template-argument* can be](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#1) such a *type-id*.

Answer (score 0):

It's in [`[decl.name]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name), as one of the productions of [*type-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#nt:type-id)

> [ Example:
>
> ```
>    int                 // int i
>    int *               // int *pi
>    int *[3]            // int *p[3]
>    int (*)[3]          // int (*p3i)[3]
>    int *()             // int *f()
>    int (*)(double)     // int (*pf)(double)
> ```
>
> name respectively the types “`int`”, “pointer to `int`”, “array of 3 pointers to `int`”, “pointer to array of 3 `int`”, “function of (no parameters) returning pointer to `int`”, and “pointer to a function of (`double`) returning `int`”. — end example ]

`int(char)` is read “function of (`char`) returning `int`”